# TSC barcode printer TSPL TSPL2 programming

Tags: java, printing, barcode, thermal-printer

My concept is I want to read this all from text file and print it on `TSC` printer using Java .The text file ( Template ) should be like this

```
[Definitions]

{Size}=SIZE 3.00, 6.00
{Speed}=SPEED 6
{Density}=DENSITY 7
{Direction}=DIRECTION 1
{Reference}=REFERENCE 18,0
{Home}=HOME
{Clear}=CLS
{BR}=013010
{Print}=PRINT 1

[Header]

{BR}{Size};
{BR}{Speed};
{BR}{Density};
{BR}{Direction};
{BR}{Reference};
{BR}{Clear};


[Detail]

    {BR}TEXT 575,590,"calibri.TTF",90,8,8,"<TKTNUMBER>";
```

but i am not getting how to call this in my java program,how to call this placeholder from java program this template is use for printing on thermal printer

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command :

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("copy /c <prn-file path> <printer network path>");`